# Haskell Curried Map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I understand you can:

```
> f = map (+1)
> f [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

However, what if you do:

```
> g = map (+) [1,2,3]
> :t g
g :: Num a => [a -> a]
```

I am not sure how to use g. What are its input & output?

Comment: The question is predicated on a false assumption. There are no inputs or outputs; `g` is not a function.

Comment: `[a -> a]` is exactly what it says - a list of functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One could, for example, apply each element of the list to a specific value:

```
> map (\f -> f 3) g
[4,5,6]
```

Or you could apply each function in the list to values in the corresponding position of another list:

```
> zipWith (\f x -> f x) g [30,300,3000]
[31,302,3003]
```

Or you could pattern match on the list, or use it in a list comprehension, or index it with `(!!)`, or, or, or... there are endless possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`; it takes an number and returns a function that increases its argument.

`map (+) [1, 2, 3]`, then, is equivalent to `[(+ 1), (+ 2), (+ 3)]`. One way to use such a list of functions is with the `Applicative` instance of `[]`, which allows you to apply each function in a list to each value in another list. For example:

```
[(+ 1), (+ 2), (+ 3)] <*> [5] == [6, 7, 8]
```